# How to view Links collection of MailItem in Outlook

Tags: outlook

In Outlook I can link a contact to another contact. If you have the option set you can see the links on the contact form. But what I really want to do is link a contact from a public folder to a mail message. Then when I send the email to another user within my domain, I want them to be able to open the original contact in the public folder. So when we talk about x contact, the recipient will be able to easily open and view or edit the contact. Of course this depends on having access to the public folder but here that is not a problem.

Adding the link as you see here is easy enough:

```
Dim msg As MailItem
Set msg = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox).Items.Add

'add a link to the contact
Call msg.Links.Add(myContactItem)
```

[MailItem.Links Property (Outlook)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867812(v=office.14).aspx)

How do I make the links collection of the mailItem visible to the recipient similar to the links in a contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. MS is deprecating the Links collection in the Outlook Object Model and the corresponding UI. Expect the Links collection property to be null in the future.

Comment: Well imagine that. Thanks MS. Here's the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228679(v=office.15).aspx